# Rails: Receiving a relative date as a string. How can I use it in date arithmetic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a rails script which accepts command line parameters. One param is a relative date - i.e. 3.months.ago

This option is passed to my script as a string. How can I use that string as a relative date? My instinct is to cast it, but not sure to what...

For instance:

```
>> Event.count(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 3.months.ago])
=> 18883
>>
>> user_date = "3.months.ago"
>> Event.count(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", user_date])
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "3.months.ago"
```

Comment: That's a string, not a date. You could eval it, but a bit evil. You don't really cast in Ruby. You could pull it apart and send, which might be good if you care about security, but you'd have to whitelist methods or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just evaluate it to get a Time instance:

```
[1] pry(main)> eval('3.months.ago').class
=> ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
[2] pry(main)> eval('3.months.ago')
=> Sun, 15 Apr 2012 00:20:25 EDT -04:00
[3] pry(main)> Event.where("created_at > ?", eval('3.months.ago')).to_sql
=> "SELECT `events`.* FROM `events`  WHERE (created_at > '2012-04-15 00:22:46')"
```

Of course, you don't want to `eval` anything that a user inputs directly. But it's a reasonable way to handle relative dates that you construct.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using a gem like [Chronic](http://chronic.rubyforge.org/) which can handle constructs, at least in English, like "tomorrow" or "three weeks from now". The main caveat is that it seems to presume "local time", which makes little sense in a web application, so you may need to do additional hacking (time zone calculations, at least) to have things work in a way that matches your user expectations.